# Apache Curator lock issue

Tags: apache-zookeeper, apache-curator

I have the following code to acquire a distributed lock:

```
    public void foo(){
      try {

        if (!lock.acquire(5, TimeUnit.MINUTES)) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Could not acquire lock");
        }

        doWork();

      } finally {
        if (lock.isAcquiredInThisProcess()) {
          lock.release();
        }
      }
    }
```

The problem I'm seeing is that sometimes the lock is created in zookeeper but the `lock.acquire(..)` call is returning `false`. So it looks like the lock is created but the client isn't aware of it and that means that all calls to the `foo()` are stuck.

Restarting the java service fixes the issue.

I'm using curator 2.11.0.

Anyone with an idea on what could be wrong?

Comment: What do you mean by "the lock is created"? Every participant in a lock will create a ZNode. The ZNode with the lowest sequence count holds the lock.

Comment: I mean that the ZNode is created in zk but the client think that it isn't.

Comment: You'd need to come up with a test that proves this. How do you know the ZNode is created? Curator's lock recipes are extremely well tested and widely used. I'd be very surprised if this was true.

Comment: I look in zk and I can see the node. Yeah thats the hard thing, it works almost all cases so I haven't been able to reproduce it in a test environment.

Comment: You see "a" node. How do you know it's your node? Is only 1 process involved in the lock. Maybe that's a node from another process? Note: by default Curator stores the IP of the address that created the node. Look at the node's data to see the IP.

Comment: Yeah the node is prefixed by a guid so I know it is is the "my" node. Thanks for the ip, will check that next time the issue occurs.

Comment: All nodes in the lock path will have a GUID. How do you that _your client_ created that node. Another client might have created the node.

Comment: Yeah but it's from the path /my-guid/locks/... and my-guid is only from on specific client